# In which case spark dirver program could run out of memory?

Tags: apache-spark

I execute on YARN with 32 executors and `--driver-memory 2G` option.
I got exception as follow

```
ERROR actor.ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I wonder in which case driver could run out of memory.
Since I do everything with RDD (e.g. map, filter, reduce, groupBy and etc), driver program should not require much memory.

By the way, the program generate too many tasks, there are more than 200 stages and many of them have 40000 tasks. Could this cause the problem?

Here is the main logic:

```
class A { def id:VertexID }
class B ...


val data:RDD[A] = ...
val start_v:RDD[VertexID] = ...
val edges:RDD[Edge[B]] = ...

  def spanning(inits:RDD[VertexId],iterations:Int):RDD[VertexId] = {
    val medge = edges.groupBy(_.srcId) persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    var nodes = inits
    for (
      i<- 1 to iterations
    ){
      val step1 = nodes map (x => x -> x) join( medge )
      val step2 = step1 flatMap ( x=> x._2._2 map (_.dstId))
      nodes = (step2 ++ nodes) 
    }
    nodes distinct()
  }

    val result = spanning( start_v,100 )
    val sample_data = data map (x => x.id -> x) join( result map (x=> x -> 1) ) map (_._2._1)

    println(sample_data.count())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to [review which methods are actions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations) and which are not, as actions pull back to the driver:

> On the other hand, reduce is an action that aggregates all the
>   elements of the RDD using some function and returns the final result
>   to the driver program

Comment: Hi, I review my code. reduce is only used on a very small data set. Besides, reduce only return the result which is a very small object.

Comment: How am I supposed to know that without any actual code? You listed reduce as a non-driver action, so I answered. List code and maybe we can help better

Answer (score 0):

If you use RDD.collect(), your driver program may potentially use a lot of memory as it collect all data from executors into driver's memory for further handling like output to external systems. If that is the case, you can consider alternative like RDD.foreachPartition which will register a function that will get executed at the executors. This way all data will not flow back to driver's program.

Comment: RDD.print() will also get data back to driver but by default it'll only take the first 10 records, unless you explicitly specify a large number by calling print(largeNumber).